# Optimize / redesign this java code

Tags: loops, array-algorithms

folks.
I need help or advice on decision making about a a design pattern (or sort of such) to uuse:
Have an application, running on weblogic via EJBs.  Part of application deals with the the very large data set of objects (tens or hundreds of thousands) and constructs an xml file consisting of several sections.

Resulting XML looks similar to this:

```
<sect1>
    <page>
       <detail_1>something</detail_1>
       <detail_2>something</detail_2>
       ... ... a lot of these
       <detail_10000000>something</detail_10000000>
    </page>
</sect1>
<sect2>
    <page>
       <detail_1>something</detail_1>
       <detail_2>something</detail_2>
       ... ... a lot of these
       <detail_10000000>something</detail_10000000>
    </page>
</sect2>
<sect3>
    <page>
       <detail_1>something</detail_1>
       <detail_2>something</detail_2>
       ... ... a lot of these
       <detail_10000000>something</detail_10000000>
    </page>
</sect3>
```

The problem is that each of the "section_i" is constructed by application looping over this large data sets and doing some operations on them before writing the actual xml.  I can't control the operations, they are to stay.  But since each section is done sequentially - one after another, every time the list get's traversed from the beginning to end.  I am thinking of making this multi-threaded - that is designate a thread to creating each section of the xml.  But have doubts about the performance.  With existing system it takes a very long time, but eventually completes.  If I move to multi-threading, I fear that on a server where other apps are running this will create other issues.
Is there any known pattern for a solution to such problems?  I tried to change use of ArrayList to hash-represented sets, but this speeds up the lookup, not the traversal time.
Any advise?  Anyone know any resources to check?

Comment: What is the point of the xml? Does it get consumed by some other service? Looping over hundreds of thousands of strings is not that slow. I think you need to identify the what is causing the slowdowns and optimize that.

Comment: @Danny, those are not strings, what gets looped over.  Sorry, for confusion, the xml I posted is a sample of the result.  The objects that are in the list represent the records in the database, having fields of various types.  And objects are also operated on.  Not just written to xml.  Xml gets operated by other architectural parts of the system - converted into PDF by xsl transformer in some instances.  Some specifically formatted file gets created in other instances.  So xml is a hierarchical representation of in my case it is a customer bill.  And "section"s are section of the bill